# Security annotations not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

My @PreAuthorize annotation is not working. From what I can see I'm doing it correctly. Note, this is update to a post I deleted because I realized I should copy in the whole xml files instead of snippets.

Here is my security-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern='/*' access='permitAll' />
    <form-login login-page="/contacts" authentication-failure-url="/security/loginfail" default-target-url="/contacts" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/contacts"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Here is the web.xml with the security configuration at the top:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns  /javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

      <!-- Spring Security Configuration -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring MVC filters -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>HttpMethodFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Spring OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>


    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>5000000</max-file-size>
    </multipart-config>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

Here is the root-context.xml which is part of the context-param in web.xml. Note the root-context.xml imports the security-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<import resource="classpath:datasource-tx-jpa.xml" />

<import resource="security-context.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.apress.prospring3.ch17.service.jpa" />
```

Servlet-context which includes the global-security-context and is after the component-scan:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven validator="validator" />

<resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/web-resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
<default-servlet-handler/>


<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory  
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
-->

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jspx" />
</beans:bean>
 -->

<!--  <context:component-scan base-package="com.apress.prospring3" />  -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.apress.prospring3.ch17.web.controller" />


<!-- Enable controller method level security -->
<security:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<interceptors>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor"/>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
    p:paramName="lang"/>
</interceptors>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource"
    id="themeSource"/>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver"
    id="themeResolver" p:cookieName="theme" p:defaultThemeName="standard"/>

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application"
    p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false"/>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver"
    id="localeResolver" p:cookieName="locale"/>

<beans:bean id="validator"
    class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver"
    id="multipartResolver"/>

<!-- Tiles Configuration -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
    id="tilesViewResolver">
<beans:property name="viewClass"
    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer"
    id="tilesConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="definitions">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml</beans:value>
            <!-- Scan views directory for Tiles configurations -->
            <beans:value>/WEB-INF/views/**/views.xml</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

And my actual annotation:

```
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @RequestMapping(params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createForm(Model uiModel) {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
        uiModel.addAttribute("contact", contact);
        return "contacts/create";
   }
```

Comment: When you say "not working" do you mean that someone can submit the contact creation form without being logged in? Or does it never ask anyone to log in? How does it fail?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - someone can submit without being logged in.

Comment: Your controller class is in **com.apress.prospring3.ch17.web.controller** package?

Comment: Do you have cglib in your classpath?

Comment: Yes the controller is in the listed package. Yes cglib is in the classpath. If it wasn't wouldn't I have gotten some sort of error message?

Comment: Can you call some new method (annotated with @PreAuthorize) of some **another** new spring bean from inside of createForm method? Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

Try [enabling the `@PreAuthorize`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/el-access.html#el-pre-post-annotations) annotation.